# Python - How to interact with system tray popup

Tags: python, pywinauto

I want to autologin to an app via its system tray icon.
I use the pywinauto module to interact with the tray icon to launch the app and now I have a popup who ask me to log on.
But... I don't know how to interact with it !

This is my icon :
[Tray Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okf5O.png)

Here, an extract of my code (works fine) :

```py
_pApp = Application().connect(path='my_app_dir')
taskbar.ClickSystemTrayIcon(1)
_pApp.PopupMenu.menu_item('submenu').click_input()
_pApp.PopupMenu.menu_item('another_submenu').click_input()
```

How can I interact with the popup authentication window below ?

[Popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSndR.png)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found exactly the expected behavior :)

Thank you Vasily Ryabov ! Your method is very helpful !

I do not use 'send_keys' anymore.

```py
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from pywinauto import taskbar
from pywinauto.application import Application
[...]

_user = "TOTO"
_pass = "TOTOPASS"
app_dir = r'C:\Program Files\Common Files\App\App.exe'
icon_list = list()

# Getting the name of the icons in the sys tray
for i in range(0, 13):
    app_sti = taskbar.SystemTrayIcons.wrapper_object()
    app_stv = pulse_sti.button(i).info.text
    icon_list.append(app_stv)

# Looking for my app name
try:
    if "App_name" in str(icon_list):
       app = Application().connect(path=app_dir)
       taskbar.ClickSystemTrayIcon("App name")
       app.PopupMenu.menu_item('menu').click_input()
       app.PopupMenu.menu_item('menu -> submenu').click_input()
       app_auth = Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re="Title*", timeout=5)
       app_auth_window = app_auth.window(title_re="Title*")
       app_auth_window.child_window(title="User :", control_type="Edit").set_text(_user)
       app_auth_window.child_window(title="Password :", control_type="Edit").set_text(_pass)
       app_auth_window.child_window(title="Connect", control_type="Button").click()
except Exception as error:
    showwarning("Error", "App not found !")
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution with **pywinauto.keyboard**. I don't know if it's clean but it works.

```py
from pywinauto.keyboard import *
[...]
send_keys(_user)
send_keys("{VK_TAB}")
send_keys(_pass)
send_keys("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: It's not clear what happened on previous attempt. I mean which code you've tried and the full traceback of error. Maybe you need `Application(backend="uia")` to see the UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I re-write a part of my code :

```py
from pywinauto import taskbar
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.keyboard import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

[...]

app_dir = r'C:\Program Files\Common Files\App\App.exe'
_user = "TOTO"
_pass = "TOTOPASS"

# Check if my app has its system tray icon in the taskbar
for i in range(0, 10):
     tsIcon = taskbar.SystemTrayIcons.wrapper_object()
     tsValue = tsIcon.button(i).info.text
     # If I find it, the code click on it and its menu until the popup auth window come
     if "App_name" in tsValue:
        _pApp = Application().connect(path=app_dir)
        taskbar.ClickSystemTrayIcon(i)
        _pApp.PopupMenu.menu_item('menu').click_input()
        _pApp.PopupMenu.menu_item('menu->submenu').click_input()
        time.sleep(2)
        # When the popup window comes out, I run 'send_keys'
        send_keys(_user)
        send_keys("{VK_TAB}")
        send_keys(_pass)
        send_keys("{ENTER}")
     else:
        showwarning("Error", "App not found !")
[...]
```

My code seems good ? There is another "most clean" method ?

Thanks

Comment: It would be better to wait for new window properly: `app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title="Paste Login window title here", timeout=2)`. If you don't know the title, try this code: `print([w.window_text() for w in Application(backend="uia").connect(path=app_dir).windows()])` to get all top level window titles. Read more about backends here: [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Comment: Thank you  Vasily Ryabov ! Your answer is very hepful :)
My answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59032452/11758711